# 'Flutter doctor -v' STUCK at 'downloading SDK from Flutter Engine'

Tags: flutter

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] 
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\DELL>flutter doctor -v 
Checking Dart SDK version... 
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f3
    2...
```

This is where the console gets stuck. The issue began when VS code prompted me to upgrade the flutter extension. I felt it was taking too much time (possibly due to a network error) so I cancelled it. Now my Android Studio Emulator can not get connected with the VS code.

```
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     E:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven:
            Mobile? true
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? false
            Flutter Repo? false
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven\.flutter
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven\.flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven\vendor\flutter
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Writer's Haven\writerHaven\vendor\flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         E:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\flutter
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\flutter for flutter.bat
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         E:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[11:12:25 AM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for dart.exe
```

I have also tried to change Environment Variable path and use the flutter console.bat directly using Administrator rights. Even used Git Bash but to no avail. In the end I also deleted the cache inside the flutter\bin folder. My flutter directory is

`C:\Users\DELL\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter\bin`

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed in the system?

Comment: Yes I do. Avast.

Comment: You can try this after whitelisting dart, java, gradle, studio64, vscode or any other related program.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue on windows, I think it was due a proxy thing issue. I've come across this solution in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27276#issuecomment-596381298) provided for a similar issue. I'll mention the main steps again though:

1. Go the flutter sdk folder (In my case it was in `C:\src\flutter` )
2. Go to `bin\internal`
3. Open the file `update_dart_sdk.ps1`
4. After this line of code `Import-Module BitsTransfer`, in the Try block, add the following:

   ```
   If($httpProxy = ([System.Uri] $env:http_proxy)){
   $proxyUserInfo = $httpProxy.UserInfo.Split(":")
   $proxyPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $proxyUserInfo[1] -AsPlainText -Force
   $proxyCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
      ($proxyUserInfo[0], $proxyPass)
   Start-BitsTransfer -Source $dartSdkUrl -Destination $dartSdkZip - 
      ProxyUsage Override -ProxyList ($httpProxy.Host + ":" + 
      $httpProxy.Port) -ProxyCredential $proxyCredential - 
      ProxyAuthentication Basic    
   }Else{
     Start-BitsTransfer -Source $dartSdkUrl -Destination $dartSdkZip
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just run `flutter doctor` again. it will download again

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a this solution found [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/49050/575853881)

1. delete folder in your sdk path flutter/bin/cache (detail info here)
2. run flutter doctor -v again will trigger downloading Dart SDK
3. export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
   (detail info here)
4. flutter channel stable (one example of change flutter channel)
5. flutter doctor -v (trigger downloading SDK)

**Edit** : Other things you can try :

Delete Cache folder under flutter/bin

Open another Flutter project in VSCode

Inside the Flutter directory try running `dart --version` and updating your OP with it

Comment: The problem persists :/

Comment: try rebooting your pc, and updating flutter again, also disable your antivirus

Comment: trying to run any command leads to the same problem. "$Flutter upgrade" leads again to the above mentioned problem.

Comment: all flutter commands lead to the same dead end. I think I might have to reinstall the flutter sdk if the problem persists.

Comment: Yeah some files are probably corrupt, can't think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

i think the flutter needs a disk storage space without administrative privileges. So you can install on your D drive